# How can I show rows from one table that aren't in another table?

Tags: php, sql

I have two tables in a database, one of them is a list of 'buildings' you could create. The other is a list of buildings that have been built by users.

On one page, (cityproduction.php), it displays a list of 'buildings' you can build.
I want it to display the buildings that you can build, that you haven't already built.

Here is my code:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM [The list of built buildings] WHERE building_owner = '$user'";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $variable = $row["building_name"];    
}
```

(...)

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM [The list of ALL buildings] WHERE name != '$variable' ORDER BY id asc";
$result = mysqli_query($database,$sql) or die(mysqli_error($database));

while($rws = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){ 
echo $rws["name"]; (etc.)
```

What this is doing is only not-showing one of the buildings that the user has built, not all of them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why are you using `while` after the first query, it suppose to be a list or just a single value? because if you use `$variable` in your second query it will only have the value of the last value of the list you are getting

```
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {

  $variable =  array();

  while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

    $variable[] = $row["building_name"];    
}
```

Second query example:

```
 foreach($variable as $building) {

      $sql = "SELECT * FROM [The list of ALL buildings] WHERE name != '$building' ORDER BY id asc";
      $result = mysqli_query($database,$sql) or die(mysqli_error($database));
      $result = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);

      echo $result["name"];
    }
```

Comment: I want $variable to be a list of all the buildings built by that user - I just assumed it would store as an array, how can I have it as an array and not a single value?

Comment: `$variable = array();` before the `while` and inside the `while` use it as `$variable[] = $row['building_name'];` but after that your second query should be into a loop to do the query with each value of your array, in this case could be a `foreach` loop

Comment: @DanterNetwork You won't be able to use an array in your string like that. You could build a CSV and pass it to a SQL `in`. This will open you to second level SQL injections though.

Answer (score 1):

Without seeing the real table names or the schema it is tricky to answer accurately but you could try something along these lines:

```
SELECT * FROM `all_buildings` 
WHERE `id` not in ( 
    select `building_id` from `built_buildings` where `building_owner` = '$user'
    ) 
ORDER BY `id` asc;
```

Comment: Thank you! I had no idea that 'not in' existed - stupid me.

Answer (score 1):

Another translation of your question into SQL (besides `NOT IN`) results in a Correlated Subquery:

```
SELECT * FROM `all_buildings` AS a
WHERE NOT EXISTS 
  ( 
    select * from `built_buildings` AS b 
    where a.`id` = b.`building_id`    -- Outer Select correlated to Inner
      and b.`building_owner` = '$user'
  ) 
ORDER BY `id` asc;
```

The main advantage over `NOT IN`: it's using only two-valued-logic (`NULL` is ignored = false) while `NOT IN` uses three-valued-logic (comparison to NULL returns *unknown* which might no return what you expect)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming both of your tables have some sort of id column to relate them, with this query:

```
SELECT building_name, building_owner FROM 
    test.all_buildings a 
    LEFT JOIN test.built_buildings b ON a.id = b.building_id AND b.building_owner = ?
ORDER BY building_owner DESC, building_name;
```

(where `?` is the user), you can select all the buildings, first the ones that have been built, followed by the ones that haven't, in one query. If your tables don't have id's like that, you can join them on name instead; it should work as long as the names are distinct.

Then as you fetch the rows, you can sort them into "built" or "not built" by checking if the row has a `building_owner`.

```
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        if ($row['building_owner']) {
            $built[] = $row['building_name'];
        } else {
            $not_built = $row['building_name'];
        }
    }
}
```